# Is there a Material UI based tree select component?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui

I have been looking for a reliable component with a clear API documentation that would allow me to display a "tree view" structure for a **select input as part of a form**. The closest I have came across is [vue-treeselect](https://vue-treeselect.js.org/) with many supported features such as: disabling branch nodes, disable item selection and more; the issue is that it's only available on Vue JS. My project is using Material UI as its design system, any component that supports it would be very great. Thanks

Comment: Material-UI has a TreeView component, though it is still in the [lab](https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/). https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/#tree-view

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your comment. However, it seems that TreeView component cannot be integrated with Text Field or any other form element in Material UI. My use case would be to use it as a form input.

Comment: Autocomplete also has some support for hierarchical options (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#grouped), though it only easily supports a single level of grouping.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Did you ever come across anything that worked for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I've just recently came to actively work on this again. I'll let you know once I find something useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed a to deal with tree data in a project as well.  I ended up creating [MUI Tree Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-tree-select).

You can demo it in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/mikepricedev/mui-tree-select/tree/main/example?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview).

[image: Demo Screen Shot]

Comment: in this component how set value programatically ?

Answer (score 2):

I searched a lot for that in the end I made this by myself [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tree-select-sample-easy-wujtg5).
you can choose to parent or child with this and you can custom it easily.

```
    import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TreeItem from "@mui/lab/TreeItem";
import { Popover, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { TreeView, useTreeItem } from "@mui/lab";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import { useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
const data = [
  {
    id: "root",
    name: "Parent",
    children: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "Child - 1"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Child - 3",
        children: [
          {
            id: "4",
            name: "Child - 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "1root",
    name: "Parent1",
    children: [
      {
        id: "5",
        name: "Child - 1-1"
      },
      {
        id: "7",
        name: "Child - 3-1",
        children: [
          {
            id: "8",
            name: "Child - 4-1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
const CustomContent = React.forwardRef(function CustomContent(props, ref) {
  const {
    classes,
    className,
    label,
    nodeId,
    icon: iconProp,
    expansionIcon,
    displayIcon
  } = props;

  const {
    disabled,
    expanded,
    selected,
    focused,
    handleExpansion,
    handleSelection,
    preventSelection
  } = useTreeItem(nodeId);

  const icon = iconProp || expansionIcon || displayIcon;

  const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    preventSelection(event);
  };

  const handleExpansionClick = (event) => {
    handleExpansion(event);
  };

  const handleSelectionClick = (event) => {
    handleSelection(event);
  };

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions
    <div
      className={clsx(className, classes.root, {
        [classes.expanded]: expanded,
        [classes.selected]: selected,
        [classes.focused]: focused,
        [classes.disabled]: disabled
      })}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      ref={ref}
      style={{ padding: "3px 0" }}
    >
      <div onClick={handleExpansionClick} className={classes.iconContainer}>
        {icon}
      </div>
      <Typography
        onClick={handleSelectionClick}
        component="div"
        className={classes.label}
      >
        {label}
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
});
const CustomTreeItem = (props) => (
  <TreeItem ContentComponent={CustomContent} {...props} />
);

export default function RichObjectTreeView({ formik, edit }) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [equipmentItem, setEquipmentItem] = useState("");
  const [equipmentId, setEquipmentId] = useState("");
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  const renderTree = (nodes) => (
    <CustomTreeItem key={nodes.id} nodeId={nodes.id} label={nodes.name}>
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
        ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
        : null}
    </CustomTreeItem>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        variant="standard"
        required={false}
        label="Equipment Item"
        name="equipmentItem"
        id="equipmentItem"
        defaultValue={equipmentItem}
        value={equipmentItem}
        className="w-100"
        inputProps={{ readOnly: !edit }}
        onClick={handleClick}
      />

      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <TreeView
          aria-label="icon expansion"
          defaultSelected={equipmentId}
          selected={equipmentId}
          defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
          onNodeSelect={(e, id) => {
            setEquipmentId(id);
            setEquipmentItem(e.target.innerText);
          }}
          sx={{
            height: 200,
            flexGrow: 1,
            minWidth: "200px",
            overflowY: "auto"
          }}
        >
          {data.map((item, i) => renderTree(item))}
        </TreeView>
      </Popover>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: doesnt work for a moment, fresh example?

Comment: it took a sec to load but it works great, good job Samira

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select (it also has a theme for mui like style)

Answer (score 0):

You can install this library here.
it cover both reactive forms and ngforms too
Check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-tree-select-input

Comment: You can't really use this with react cause it has Angular as a dependancy